# Monitoring Server Accessibility(Ping) and Uptime of Windows EC2 instances in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, monitoring

I have a requirement to monitor Memory, Disk, Paging File Usage, Logon Errors, Server Accessibility(Ping) and Uptime of Windows EC2 instances.

I have monitored Memory, Disk, Logon Errors and Paging File Usage using ***Cloud Watch*** custom metrics. I was able to do these because I found these counters in my Windows ***Performance Monitor***. But how do I monitor Server Accessibility(Ping) and Uptime?

Comment: Please define *Server Accessibility*: ping, listening on some port, etc...

Comment: I have changed the question.Please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

There are many services which monitor server uptime and response times. [Pingdom](https://www.pingdom.com) is a commonly used service. It is most known for http monitoring, but also supports ping checks (among others).

If you want a more integrated solution you can look into setting up a monitoring suite like [Nagios](https://www.nagios.com/) or [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/). Most can monitor performance data on the severs as well as external reachability.

I have also compiled an extensive list of [windows server performance monitoring tools](https://checkpanel.com/resources/windows-server-performance-monitoring-tools) which might help you in finding the right solution.

Comment: Thanks.Anyways I found it in Performance Monitor Section. Under System---> System Up time. Using this I was able to monitor it.